# passing data to provider - setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm fetching data from the local database using SQflite in my main.dart and passing it to ProvideRecords widget using FutureProvider :

```dart
Future<List<WeightRecord>> _getRecords() async {
  List<WeightRecord> records = await RecordsDatabase.instance.getRecords();

  return records;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureProvider<List<WeightRecord>?>(
        create: (context) {
          return _getRecords();
        },
        initialData: [],
        catchError: (_, error) => [
          WeightRecord(
              date: DateTime.now(), weight: 00.0, note: 'hasError: $error')
        ],
        child: ProvideRecords(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then in the ProvideRecords widget I pass the data again to another provider :

```dart
class ProvideRecords extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProvideRecords({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<List<WeightRecord>?>(builder: (context, list, child) {
                return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context) => RecordsListModel()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ButtonMode())
              ],
              builder: (context, child) {

         Provider.of<RecordsListModel>(context, listen: true)
                    .updateRecordsList(list);

                return Home(list: list);
              });
        }
     
    });
  }
}
```

the code works but I'm getting `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`  because I'm using `Provider.of<RecordsListModel>(context, listen: true).updateRecordsList(list);`  in the builder function. However I couldn't find another way of passing the data from FutureProvider to the RecordListModel, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mainly an issue of how you have structured your code

Its recommended to have your multiproviders at the apps entry point..

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
       //my providers here
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ButtonMode())
       ... material app
```

then when adding data no need to set listen to true

```
 Provider.of<RecordsListModel>(context, listen: false)
                    .updateRecordsList(list);
```

since home depends on data from the above provider use a consumer

```
Home(list: list);
```

// consume your provider

```
Consumer<RecordsListModel>(
              builder:
                  (context, RecordsListModel recordsP, child) {
                return Home(list:recordsP.list);
              },
            )
```